# Python 3 print to file creating errant new lines

Tags: python, python-3.x, newline, spacing

I wrote code to read in url and IP data with IP as the key for urls visited. I am attempting to print the IP key then the number of url visits for each.

The problem is that when printing to my file there is a new line after some IPs. 
Here is the output section of code:

```
`for key, value in ipVisit.items():                                     
    outputF.write(key + " " + str(len(ipVisit[key]))+ '\n' )`
```

Even if I increase or decrease the number of spaces between key and # of visits the third output is always the only one to be on one line. Here is the output:

```
194.33.212.111
   28
12.65.4.100
   28
205.23.104.49   31
205.23.104.49
   29
```

Did I do something stupid with my loop? How can I fix this?

Comment: `key.rstrip()` and `str(len(ipVisit[key])).rstrip()` strips any whitespace at the end of the string, including newlines.

Answer (score 2):

One thing I've found to be very helpful when writing to files is to ignore the `write` method entirely:

```
for key, value in ipVisit.items():
    print(key + " " + str(len(ipVisit[key])), file=outputF)
```

This has the possibly-great side effect of outputting to stdout if `outputF==None`, which I've taken advantage of for command line programs in the past (passing in the output file vs. `-` or something).

Using print, you'll get the newline semantics that you're familiar with and the commenter's suggestion of `.rstrip()` will take care of any leftover errant newline characters.

EDIT: It might also be wise to avoid string building with the `+` operator and instead use the `format` method. Also, you have the value already form your for loop, there's no need to index into `ipVisit` again:

```
for key, value in ipVisit.items():
    print('{} {}'.format(key, len(value)), file=outputF)
    # or rstrip if there's still extra newlines
    print('{} {}'.format(key.rstrip(), len(value)), file=outputF)  # this will only work if you're sure `key` is a str
```

Comment: I tried the code you provided but I'm still getting the exact same output

Comment: Interesting! See the slightly updated version above with some more agressive `rstrip`-ing. If it still happens, please update your question with some examples of the exact values of the keys--use `[repr(k) for k in ipVisit.keys()]` so we can see what we're really dealing with. (Or, perhaps, `repr(ipVisit)`)